# Truffle-config outputSelection is not working

Tags: truffle, truffle-compile

I'm trying to only select the truffle compile output using the `outputSelection` JSON config in truffle-config.json. But when I run `truffle compile --all`, the build JSON files still contains everything. Am I not configuring it correctly?

```
compilers: {
      solc: {
          version: "0.6.12",
          settings: {  
            optimizer: {
              enabled: false,
              runs: 200
            },
            "outputSelection": {
              '*': {
                 '': [
                     "ast"
                 ],
                '*': [
                  "evm.bytecode.object",
                  "evm.deployedBytecode.object",
                  "abi",
                  "evm.bytecode.sourceMap",
                  "evm.deployedBytecode.sourceMap",
                  "metadata"
                ]
              },
          },
          evmVersion: "istanbul"
        }
      }
  },
```